# How async await work in a web application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, async-await

This could be a basic question. How can we use an async await web api call in an MVC application? Suppose that I am using a submit button in my mvc ajax form and in the controller I have an asynchronous web api call , in this scenario do I have to wait for the async operation to complete before I return the ActionResult?

I hope I need to wait until the task complete since my ajax script in the client side needs a result.

Please explain your insight and experience in similar scenario

Answer (score 0):

To be truly async you will need to await the response before sending it back to the client.  Your controller may look something like:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Read()
{
    var data = await _asyncMethod();
    return Ok(data);
}
```

So the response will not go immediately back to the client UNTIL the `await` has finished.  Using just the `async/await` keywords does not create a new thread, but rather tells the current thread the response may not be immediately available so don't block on the thread waiting for it. For a very busy controller this can increase responsiveness so the controller can respond to other requests without truly finishing the first request, and WHEN the awaited async method finishes it will send the response back to the client.